# can anyone give the answer?...this question has a paradox

Tags: complex-numbers

Find $\cos(z)$, given 
$$z=i\ln(2-\sqrt3))$$

Comment: I'm getting the answer as 2 but the range of cos is between [-1,1]...can someone give me a clarification

Comment: What's the paradox? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note,

$$\cos z = \cos( i\ln(2-\sqrt3))=\cosh(\ln(2-\sqrt3))=\frac12(2-\sqrt3 + \frac1{ 2-\sqrt3 })=2$$

So, it is actually the range of $\cosh(z)$ after converting to real space.

Comment: This doesn’t explain his question (in the comments). He got the answer as 2 already

Comment: @Gareth good note overlooked it

Comment: i suppose u are taking limits in your note?

Comment: im a tenth grader so please explain according to my level :)

Answer (score 2):

The range of $cos(x)$ is in [-1 .. 1] *on the real line only*.  When extended to the complex plane, $cos(z)$ has a complex range , which goes outside that interval for non-real inputs.

Comment: oh ... fine..thank you

Comment: what is the range of cos in the complex plane then?